# How to use extra font on Forge design automation with AutoCAD Plot API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I found missing characters in plotted PDF when I evaluated Autocad plot API with forge design automation. Missing characters are typed in the Japanese font "MS P Gothic".

Please tell me how to use extra font on Forge design automation with AutoCAD Plot API.

"PlotToPDF" command works fine for this issue, but our existing add-in didn't use the export command.

[Result of PlotToPDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMvzm.png)
[Result of AutoCAD PlotAPI with Forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MoWD.png)

Comment: Can you please share the non-confidential drawing for us to understand the behavior?
`Please tell me how to use extra font on Forge design automation with AutoCAD Plot API` ,

Comment: Sure, I can put Dwg and sample source code. but I can't find the issue now. 
I will put the materials if the problem recurs.

Comment: Thank you, in case if you are looking to substitute Big Font, you may try this example. Uses LISP script. https://github.com/MadhukarMoogala/acadio-snippets/blob/master/case4.md

Comment: @randomguy I just found the cause of this issue. Its a "22.0" version problem , and I checked correct output on "23.0". Thank you.
The annoucement URL is below .
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/ja/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/kA23A000000es3B.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the cause of this issue. Its a "22.0" version problem , and I checked correct output on "23.0".